# Poisson PDE solution regularity

Tags: regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

I want to know the required conditions for the solution of the Poisson equation to exist in $H^2(\Omega)$. I am considering two cases.

Let $\Omega\subset[-1,1]^d$ be a bounded set with

1) $\partial\Omega$ being $C^2$.

2) $\partial\Omega$ is Lipschitz.

Let $u$ solve the Poisson PDE,

$\triangle u=f$

$\gamma u=0$

$\gamma$ is the trace operator. What conditions on $f$ provide that $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ for 1 and 2. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look up elliptic regularity, it's a pretty standard development.

Comment: I have looked at the elliptic regularity result however I am a bit confused about it. Most of then relate to Holder continuous spaces. However I am interested in $H^2$. I believe there is a connection but I do not know about it. I have read the $C^1$ boundary would be sufficient to provide to solution be in $H^2$ I wanted to know about the boundary being Lipschitz.

Comment: $C^2$ on a bounded domain gets you $H^2$ for free, do you see why?

Comment: I cannot see it. How does the boundary smoothness tell me about the regularity of the solution? I am new to this stuff. So not sure how this works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I meant if the solution is $C^2$ then you get $H^2$; you get this $C^2$ property from the Holder inclusions.

Comment: Yes that I understand, I even found out the result for 1. However now I am looking for the result corresponding to the Lipschitz boundary case. So far I have come across the requirement that $\Omega$ is a polygon then $u\in H^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f\in L^2(\Omega)$:

In 1), $u\in H^2(\Omega)$.

In 2), $u\in H^2_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$.

See for instance the following paper and the references therein:

> G. Savaré. Regularity results for elliptic equations in Lipschitz domains. J. Funct. Anal. 152 (1998), no. 1, 176--201.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I  was looking for.